# How to populate textInput spacer with hover menu interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to populate a textInput spacer with a text file's contents. The said text file needs to be selected via a hover menu, which I am using for the first time. The interface is easy enough to set up, but the mechanics of populating the text box are trickier than I expected. I am probably missing something really simple because I am a rookie in this area.

Here is an example:-

```
<li><a>Jul 15, 2018</a></li>
    <script>
        var currentBaseValue;
        $("#selectedBaseRelease").load("location_of_some_file", function() {
            loadbaseText(currentBaseValue);
        });
    </script>
```

A bigger picture is here, which includes the loadbaseText function, among other things:-

```
https://jsfiddle.net/kehliah/z6y87x35/10/
```

Notice in the JS Fiddle example how two menu options under SP1-T simply point to remote web pages of pure text. (This is for example purposes only.) If I can get the two different loads to work, I can make appropriate edits on my end to point to files within my company's firewall/domain.

What am I missing? How can I get the contents of either SP1-T option to appear in the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your jsfiddle, I could not find where you were actually calling any of your functions when clicking the `<li>` elements, this is made harder by the fact that all of your CSS, HTML, and JQuery are all together.

Anyway, here is one way of doing what you requested using JQuery. At the moment, which ever `<li>` element you click on replaces the `textarea` text with the text of that `<li>` element.

```js
function populateTextArea(element) {
  $("#baseText").text($(element).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a onclick="populateTextArea(this);">Aug 30, 2018</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="populateTextArea(this);">Jul 15, 2018</a></li>
</ul>

<textarea id="baseText"></textarea>
```